# chronological comparisons within rows in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, database

I am using t-sql.

I have a simple table called `mytable`

It looks like this:

```
ID    Num    Date
1      0     2015-01-01 00:00:00
1      0     2015-01-02 00:00:00
1      1     2015-01-03 00:00:00
1      2     2015-01-04 00:00:00
2      0     2015-01-01 00:00:00
2      1     2015-02-01 00:00:00
2      0     2015-03-01 00:00:00
3      1     2014-01-01 00:00:00
3      2     2014-01-02 00:00:00
4      2     2015-02-01 00:00:00
4      0     2015-02-02 00:00:00
4      2     2015-02-05 00:00:00
```

The situation with this table is simply that any time a value of `1` or `2` has been entered into the table, the values that come later (chronologically speaking) cannot be a `0`. This is a data entry error and must be fixed by changing the `0` to a `2`.

So, in the simplified example above, `ID` has an error for person `2` and `4`.

For person `2`, somebody keyed in a `0` on `2015-01-01 00:00:00`, whereas for person `4`, somebody keyed in a `0` at `2015-01-01 00:00:00`.

I am new to SQL and honestly would rather just export the whole thing as a csv, open it in R, find the problems, and then update values with an update statement back in the database. But I feel like this is an opportunity to get better at SQL -- unfortunately, I'm stuck.

Here I need some way to compare rows within a table to each other, as them being group by ID, yet also to consider this chronological situation. I've tried a cartesian join with a `CASE` statement, which didn't work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: 7.0. Yes, I'm working on a very old system.

Comment: Do you only want 0 entries or anything less than a prior record?

Comment: just looking for entries with a 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will select all *problematic* records:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable AS t
WHERE Num = 0 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM mytable
                          WHERE Num IN (1,2) AND ID = t.ID AND Date < t.Date)
```

It selects all `Num=0` records which have either a `Num=1` *or* a `Num=2` *preceding* record for the same `ID`.

**Output:**

```
ID  Num Date
------------------
2   0   2015-03-01
4   0   2015-02-02
```

To update the table simply do:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET Num = 2
FROM mytable AS t
WHERE Num = 0 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM mytable
                          WHERE Num IN (1,2) AND ID = t.ID AND Date < t.Date)
```

Comment: can you please explain what `SELECT 1` means? What is the use of the number `1`?

Comment: @MattO'Brien `SELECT 1` means that simply a `1` is being selected for each record of `mytable` satisfying the criteria of the `WHERE` clause. This is all we need for `EXISTS` to work!

Answer (score 0):

You can join a table back to itself and put the logic in, like this:

```
select *
from mytable t
join mytable p on t.id = p.id 
                   and t.date > p.date 
                   and t.num < p.num
```

this will give you "extra" rows if there is more than one prior problem.  To fix this you can group by:

```
select id, Date, max(priornum) as max_prior 
from (
  select t.id, t.Date, p.num as priornum
  from mytable t
  join mytable p on t.id = p.id 
                and t.date > p.date 
                and t.num < p.num
) sub
group by id, Date
```

or use over and distinct (for more modern server versions):

```
select distinct t.id, t.num, t.Date,
                max(p.num) OVER (partition by t.id, t.Date) as max_prior
from mytable t
join mytable p on t.id = p.id 
                and t.date > p.date 
                and t.num < p.num
```